# How to change language of UI for current user in Roundcube using a script

Tags: php, javascript, roundcube

I am using Roundcube as a webmail client and need to write a script in order to change language of UI for current user.

Does anybody have any idea of how to do that? I know that there is a table `users` which has a field `language`. The problem consists on how to get current username using a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the language:

```
// Define $customLanguage as the result of a SQL query or session
// A valid value looks like "en_GB"
$customLanguage = $_SESSION["language"]

$rcmail = rcmail::get_instance();
$rcmail->config->set('language', $customLanguage);
$rcmail->load_language($customLanguage);
$rcmail->user->save_prefs(array("language"=>$customLanguage));
//...rest of script...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I guess I need to include some libraries before trying to execute those statements you have mentioned. Because if I run them as they are I am getting following error: Fatal error: Class 'rcmail' not found in /var/www/roundcube/skins/myskin/test.php. Could you please give me more detailed information about it? Because I am new bee here in roundcube and I am creating a new skin and need to provide two links in order to switch between languages (in my specific case they are Russian and English languages). Thank you!

Comment: The `rcmail` class is defined in `/program/include/rcmail.php`.

Comment: Sorry Rob. I have made a mistake. Now it is working fine. Except you need to add 3 more commands: $rcmail->load_language($customLanguage); $a=array("language"=>$customLanguage);$rcmail->user->save_prefs($a);